# Why AdnroidInjector.inject(fragment) uses deprecated android.support.v4.app.Fragment

Tags: android, dagger-2, android-viewmodel, androidinjector

I'm using Dagger2 for DI in android app,

I want inject viewModel in a fragment by `AndroidInjector` and have this two line :

```
 AndroidInjection.inject(this)
 viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this, viewModelFactory).get(ProductDetailViewModel::class.java)
```

When my fragment extends `androidx.fragment.app.Fragment` shows this error:

- the first line uses deprecated `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`
- but second uses `android.app.Fragment`

now I don't know my fragment should extends which one!

I get this error when choose one of them :

`None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied:
public open fun inject(activity: Activity!): Unit defined in dagger.android.AndroidInjection
public open fun inject(fragment: Fragment!): Unit defined in dagger.android.AndroidInjection
public open fun inject(service: Service!): Unit defined in dagger.android.AndroidInjection
public open fun inject(contentProvider: ContentProvider!): Unit defined in dagger.android.AndroidInjection`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

My mistake was using dagger-android (not dagger-android-support), and dagger-android just has :

```
 AndroidInjection.inject(this)
```

but I should use

```
 AndroidSupportInjection.inject(this)
```

that is in supportLibrary version of dagger-android that named `dagger-android-support`

Answer (score 1):

Google introduced us AndroidX and for making all developer on same page they make  Fragment deprecated and Make support fragment part of AndroidX.so you must need to user support fragment for same with AnroidX which part of jetpack....

https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/

Comment: have you idea about it how to resolve androidx 'injector: AppComponent' is deprecated. Consumers should switch to support.v4.app.Fragment

Answer (score 0):

The androidx is refactored library namespace.

> AndroidX is a major improvement to the original Android Support
>   Library. Like the Support Library, AndroidX ships separately from the
>   Android OS and provides backward-compatibility across Android
>   releases. AndroidX fully replaces the Support Library by providing
>   feature parity and new libraries.[see here](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/)

so I suggest you to first you should migrate the code to the androidx.
to do that follow.

Refactor>migrate to Androidx.

and kudos you're done no more conflicts with library version.

Comment: I use androidX in my project. but the viewModel and AndroidInjector uses different fragment classes that has conflict!

Comment: Then use the same androidx for both

Comment: These two line of code is part of ViewModel and Dagger library.